# Re-process all nagios data with pnp4nagios

Tags: nagios

I have moved to a new `nagios` installation (new server). I have transfered the data from the original server (`/var/log/nagios2/archives`) to my new server (`/var/log/nagios3/archives`) (I think they have compatible format). Now I would like to regenerate the pnp4nagios graphs using this historical data.

This is the command I have to process data on the fly:

```
/usr/lib/pnp4nagios/libexec/process_perfdata.pl --bulk=/var/lib/pnp4nagios/perfdata/host-perfdata
```

But this is just processing new data in `/var/lib/pnp4nagios/perfdata/host-perfdata`.

I have several questions:

- Where does pnp4nagios store the processed data (graphs)?
- How can I force pnp4nagios to regenerate all graphs?

Answer (score 1):

> - Where does pnp4nagios store the processed data (graphs)?

`process_perfdata.pl` writes the data to XML files and stored them in RRD files. The path is defined by [`$conf['rrdbase']`](http://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/webfe_cfg) in the config file ([`config.php`](http://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/install)):

```
grep -B2 rrdbase /usr/local/pnp4nagios/etc/config.php
# Directory where the RRD Files will be stored
#
$conf['rrdbase'] = "/usr/local/pnp4nagios/var/perfdata/";
```

In your case, maybe it is:

```
/usr/lib/pnp4nagios/var/perfdata/
```

> - How can I force pnp4nagios to regenerate all graphs?

If both servers have the same architecture (I mean 32bit or 64bit), copy the RRD files to the corresponding folders should work. If not, you may get the below error:

> ERROR: This RRD was created on another architecture

In this case, you need to use [`rrdtool dump`](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrddump.en.html) to write the content of an RRD in plain ASCII, then copy them to your new server and restore with [`rrdtool restore`](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdrestore.en.html).

More details: http://www.linuz.in/?p=254